# Storing image in vector bytes instead of saving file for Rust Plotters

Tags: rust

The examples of the Rust plotters crate seem to only show how to save images directly to files, how do I save the generated image as bytes in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

An example based on the [default plotters](https://github.com/plotters-rs/plotters) example.

```
use plotters::prelude::*;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut buffer_ = vec![0; 640 * 480 * 3];
    {
        let root = BitMapBackend::with_buffer(&mut buffer_, (640, 480)).into_drawing_area();
        root.fill(&WHITE)?;
        let mut chart = ChartBuilder::on(&root)
            .caption("y=x^2", ("sans-serif", 50).into_font())
            .margin(5)
            .x_label_area_size(30)
            .y_label_area_size(30)
            .build_cartesian_2d(-1f32..1f32, -0.1f32..1f32)?;

        chart.configure_mesh().draw()?;

        chart
            .draw_series(LineSeries::new(
                (-50..=50).map(|x| x as f32 / 50.0).map(|x| (x, x * x)),
                &RED,
            ))?
            .label("y = x^2")
            .legend(|(x, y)| PathElement::new(vec![(x, y), (x + 20, y)], RED));

        chart
            .configure_series_labels()
            .background_style(WHITE.mix(0.8))
            .border_style(BLACK)
            .draw()?;

        root.present()?;
    }

    let image = image::RgbImage::from_raw(640, 480, buffer_).unwrap();
    let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    image.write_to(
        &mut std::io::Cursor::new(&mut bytes),
        image::ImageOutputFormat::Png,
    )?;

    // and save to a file:
    // use std::io::Write;
    // let mut x = std::fs::File::create("teste.png").unwrap();
    // x.write_all(&bytes).unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "some-crate"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
plotters = "0.3"
image = { version = "0.24", features = ["png"] }
```

Comment: @user4815162342 just tried that now, got a "trait `Seek` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`". Indeed write_to requires Write + Seek https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.write_to

Comment: In that case the Cursor is indeed necessary, thanks for trying it out!